Change the fields that do the sorting of the view content on exposed field click
I need to sort indexed contents by "modification date" per default.
An exposed button "Relevance" would sort by relevance instead.
views sort options does not seem to allow that.
It allows to add different fields for sorting with relative weight of importance
I would need to sort by date ONLY unless i click on "sort by relevance".
It would then sort ONLY by relevance.


How could i achieve that ?

i managed to have an acceptable solutions by:

exposing both sorting fields
use the module "better exposed filters" to allow auto-submit on
change and to exclude the exposed order

Changing from one option to the other do not remove the other sorting fields from the query but change the weight of both sorting, which is fine eventually
